# Counting used attributes at runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, attributes, getattr

I'm working on a python project that requires me to compile certain attributes of some objects into a dataset. The code I'm currently using is something like the following:

```
class VectorBuilder(object):
    SIZE = 5

    def __init__(self, player, frame_data):
        self.player = player
        self.fd = frame_data

    def build(self):
        self._vector = []

        self._add(self.player)
        self._add(self.fd.getSomeData())
        self._add(self.fd.getSomeOtherData())

        char = self.fd.getCharacter()
        self._add(char.getCharacterData())
        self._add(char.getMoreCharacterData())

        assert len(self._vector) == self.SIZE
        return self._vector

    def _add(self, element):
        self._vector.append(element)
```

However, this code is slightly unclean because adding/removing attributes to/from the dataset also requires correctly adjusting the `SIZE` variable. The reason I even have the `SIZE` variable is that the size of the dataset needs to be known at runtime before the dataset itself is created.

I've thought of instead keeping a list of all the functions used to construct the dataset as strings (as in `attributes = ['getPlayer', 'fd.getSomeData', ...]`) and then defining the `build` function as something like:

```
def build(self):
    self._vector = []
    for att in attributes:
        self._vector.append(getattr(self, att)())
    return self._vector
```

This would let me access the size as simply `len(attributes)` and I only ever need to edit `attributes`, but I don't know how to make this approach work with the chained function calls, such as `self.fd.getCharacter().getCharacterData()`.

Is there a cleaner way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

## EDIT:

Some additional information and clarification is necessary.

1. I was using `__` due to some bad advice I read online (essentially saying I should use `_` for module-private members and `__` for class-private members). I've edited them to `_` attributes now.
2. The getters are a part of the framework I'm using.
3. The vector is stored as a private class member so I don't have to pass it around the construction methods, which are in actuality more numerous than the simple `_add`, doing some other stuff like normalisation and `bool->int` conversion on the elements before adding them to the vector.
4. `SIZE` as it currently stands, is a true constant. It is only ever given a value in the first line of `VectorBuilder` and never changed at runtime. I realise that I did not clarify this properly in the main post, but new attributes never get added at runtime. The adjustment I was talking about would take place at programming time. For example, if I wanted to add a new attribute, I would need to add it in the `build` function, e.g.:

   ```
   self._add(self.fd.getCharacter().getAction().getActionData().getSpeed())
   ```

   , as well as change the `SIZE` definition to `SIZE = 6`.
5. The attributes are compiled into what is currently a simple python list (but will probably be replaced with a numpy array), then passed into a neural network as an input vector. However, the neural network itself needs to be built first, and this happens before any data is made available (i.e. before any input vectors are created). In order to be built successfully, the neural network needs to know the size of the input vectors it will be receiving, though. This is why `SIZE` is necessary and also the reason for the `assert` statement - to ascertain that the vectors I'm passing to the network are in fact the size I claimed I would be passing to it.

I'm aware the code is unpythonic, that is why I'm here - the code works, it's just ugly.

Comment: Why are you using `__` attributes? Why are you storing the values in a list instead of just as plain attributes, or at least in a dict? Why do you want getters like `getCharacter()` in the first place? Why is the vector stored anywhere at all when the only time you access it, it's to replace it with a brand-new value that you immediately return? What is that `assert` actually intended to protect against? Everything you're trying to do seems overcomplicated and unpythonic, and without knowing the reasons, it's very hard to say whether one particular element of it is particularly overcomplicated

Comment: By convention attribute's whose name is all capital letters like `SIZE` means it's a constant value that won't ever be changed, yet you mention "adjusting the `SIZE` variable". If you're going to write Python code, I highly recommend reading (and following) the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggestions. Lastly, as @abarnert said, lose the `__` prefix on the attribute names, just a simple `_` to indicate something is private would be good enough here.

Comment: @martineau I _think_ the implication is that `SIZE` should get created at class-creation time (by some module-level code, presumably, since I doubt he'd use a metaclass just for that… but you never know…) and then never change. If so, it's effectively a constant. For example, if he were using a normal `__slots__` class, he could write a trivial decorator that sets `cls.SIZE = len(cls.__slots__)`, and you'd still call that a constant even though technically it's being assigned after the `type` call returns, right?

Comment: I've edited the OP to try and answer the questions posed in the above comments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing the **strings** of the attributes as a list you would like to create the input arguments from, why don't you initialize the `build` function with a list containing all the **values** returned by your getter functions?

Your `SIZE` variable would then still be the length of the dynamic argument list provided in `build(self,*args)` for example.

Comment: I need the `SIZE` before I'm ever able to access those values.

Comment: Okay. But at the same time you choose your input variables, `SIZE` should be accessible for you. Your approach seems a little complicated to me.